# How do you add types to a function that works on any objects keys without using any in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm attempting to write a function the converts the keys of an object from camelCase to snake_case in TypeScript.  This is my code:

```
  private convertToSnakeCase (obj: object): object{

    const snakeCasedObject: object = {};

    Object.keys(obj).map((key: string) => {

      const snakeCaseKey: string = _.snakeCase(key);

      snakeCasedObject[snakeCaseKey] = obj[key];
    });

    return snakeCasedObject;
  }
```

The TypeScript compiler throws the following error:

> [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.

Is it possible to write a function like this without using an explicit `any` type?  I would think that you could because the object keys should always be strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how specific you want.  One solution is to do something like

```
type AnyObj = {[key: string]: any};

private convertToSnakeCase(obj: AnyObj): AnyObj {
  // ...
}
```

I assume you just want `obj` to be an actual object, which is why you want to avoid `any`, not because you want to avoid `any` at all costs.

Comment: Yep, I did do a similar type but that still has the `any` in the type definition.

It feels to me like there should be a way to use Generics or something similar to avoid using the explicit `any` there.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you know anything else about the values?  If not, any further assumptions would be unnecessary.  `any` isn't implicitly evil, as with any feature in any language, you have to use it carefully.  In this case, it seems appropriate as is the assumption that the key is a string.

Comment: Another way to think about it is: what is important to this function?  The function must be passed a single object with keys that are strings.  The function will take those keys and mangle them, while retaining their original values.  To fulfill its contract with the rest of the program, it does not need to know anything about the type of values.  Why would you put restrictions on the values then?  Since you're not casting the values to anything or making assumptions based on the values, there really doesn't seem to be a reason to place further restrictions.